# C - allocating memory, how is it stored?

Tags: c, memory, allocation

In a K&R ebook I've been reading I came across this code:

[image: code]

And my  concern was in the line:

```
allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n
```

The code takes the address of where the buffer begins and calculates, using the index of the pointer to itself as well as the maximum buffer length constant defined above, the total remaining allocations.

Now, I understand that if you were to define a character pointer, for example, then were to arithmetically increment it by one:

```
char *ptr = "array";
ptr++;
```

Then you would get the second position, 'r' above, in memory. The, in memory, actually increments by sizeof(char) units.

---

So, given that arrays operate under the guise of pointers:

```
allocbuf + 10000
```

Is the final allocated slot in the array, correct? Since the pointer is of type char, 10000 'slots' later is actually 10,000*sizeof(char) slots later.

To clarify this concept in my mind, given a random memory address say 4210720, does 4210721 represent a bit, byte or some other metic past the address?

That is:

```
void *ptr = "sherrellbc";
ptr++;
```

Where is ptr now? Is it at some pointer between the 's' and 'h' since type void gives no information regarding step length (as in, a char pointer would increment by sizeof(char)).

In essence, what metric is memory stored using? Bits bytes, nibbles, etc?

Comment: Wait a minute: void *ptr = "..."; does not compile in the first place. ptr++ increases the memory address, whatever it is represented in, by sizeof(*ptr).

Comment: void *ptr = ".."; does compile for me. Incrementing the ptr also does not result in an error insofar as compiling is concerned. I have not done any experiments as to what is happening, however. I am not that concerned with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory addresses are byte addresses on every computer you're likely to use, even ones that don't have byte-level memory operations. Some compilers define incrementing a `void *` as adding one to the pointer, but it's not portable.

Comment: So, adding one byte. What makes the un-portable if many computers are byte addresses? Also, you say that every computer I am likely to use, what kind of computer would I be unlikely to use? I am ignorant to much of this information.

Comment: @sherrellbc Incrementing a `void*` is disallowed by the language standard because `void` has no size. For some reason, some compilers treat `sizeof(void)` as 1 but this fact is really of no interest and is only confusing you.

Comment: @sherrellbc: Jim explained why it's not portable. You're unlikely to use a computer that has, say, 9-bit bytes or nibble addressing. They could exist (they used to exist) and, who knows, one day you might write code for one, but it's not likely.

Comment: @ Jim Balter I am not confused, my true question was with respect to the metric of addressing memory. The rest of the questions seen in this post are merely a result of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing an void pointer is undefined in nature.
In case the type is defined the increment will always

```
ptr+1 = next address of ptr type.
```

Comment: Of course, that is why I did not include the * notation. I was simply incrementing the pointer to the next 'slot.' Or, is arithmetic on void pointers inherently undefined somehow?

Comment: Thats what I told it will result in undefined behaviour.Once you try to print the value of *ptr in your code the code will not compile.

Comment: I understand that dereferencing a void pointer is undefined, incrementing a void pointer is not dereferencing it. ptr++ simply moves to the next address of the pointer's type. In no way have I said that dereferencing the void pointer is what I intend to do (using * ). I only used the void type to illustrate a point.'void *ptr = "name";' followed by 'ptr+2' compiles in C. I never said I was going to try and dereference the void pointer.

Comment: Have you printed the value of ptr before and after the increment.

Comment: Nevermind. You clearly do not understand. Thanks for the reply anyway. I understand what you are saying, and I am asking a completely different question yet you keep saying the same thing repeatedly.

Comment: I am telling to print the value of ptr not *ptr.

int main()
{
        void *p = "ab";
        printf("%d\n",p);
        p++;
        printf("%d\n",p);
        p++;
        printf("%d\n",p);
}


you will find the address are printing incremented by one.This point  is already told by justin and David Schwartz.

Comment: I see, I apologize. Thank you for the suggestion. That also is another question I had above about which metrics are used for the 'next' address in memory. It has been answered that the addresses are byte-wise.

Answer (score 1):

> `allocbuf + 10000` Is the final allocated slot in the array, correct?

It's one past the end.

> To clarify this concept in my mind, given a random memory address say 4210720, does 4210721 represent a bit, byte or some other metic past the address?

A byte (3.6):

> "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member
>   of the basic character set of the execution environment.
>
> NOTE 1 It is possible to express the address of each individual byte of an object
>   uniquely."

Finally,

> `void *ptr = "sherrellbc"; \n ptr++;` - Where is ptr now?

Arithmetic on `void*` is illegal. Don't use it ;) It's like asking the compiler to take the address held by the variable and adding `sizeof(void)` to it.

If it must come down to this, use `char*` instead.

Comment: I figured arithmetic on void pointers was illegal, but I was just using it as illustrative purposes. And thank you for the catch, I now realize that adding the size of the array to the first index would of course be too far. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @sherrellbc you're welcome. pointer arithmetic (including array accesses) depends on the size and alignment of the type. as i added to the post, just use `char*` where you would use pointer arithmetic on `void*`. that is 1.

Comment: Could you cast void pointers? For whatever reason. I am not sure of any application of void pointers aside from memory placeholders or something.

Comment: void *ptr = "array, then using (char *) *ptr, perhaps.

Comment: yes. although, the cast from `void*` to `char*` is not mandatory in C: `void* vp = NULL; \n char* c = vp;`. the cast syntax here is: `char* c = (char*)vp;`.

Comment: @sherrellbc `void*` is used for pointers that might point to anything ... for instance, the value returned by `malloc` or the arguments to `memcpy`.